# How to set the clock in Debian 8

Tags: debian, clock

I though I was reasonably versed in low level maintenance, but apparently not. Help!

I'll spare you the sorry details, but my questions are:

1. What command do you use in Debian 8 instead of `hwclock`, which doesn't seem to exist any more.
2. How do you tell Debian 8 that the system clock is in UTC, while the onscreen clock should show local time. Using `UTC=yes` in `/etc/default/rcS` doesn't seem to have an effect.
3. Where can I see, in Debian 8, if the system thinks Daylight Savings is in effect or not.

Answer (score 1):

As part of the `systemd` takeover, this is now done by `timedatectl`.
To have hardware UTC use:

```
sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 0
```

and to see if DST is active:

```
$ timedatectl status
...
 RTC in local TZ: no
  DST active: no
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Ooh, I Googled "systemd", but maybe I shouldn't have. All I got was a bunch of flame wars about it.